# How to create mvc based login form in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new to using model view controller framework in php, so you guys please give me any idea to create login form with database in model view controller framework. Very thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you improve your question? MVC is a code standard, not a framework...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what framework you're using (you don't specify):

[CakePHP MVC Logon Simple Authentication and Authorization Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

[Laravel Simple and Easy Laravel Login Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication)

And your best friend when you're learning something from scratch:

[Google](http://www.google.co.uk)